# Cannot uninstall Sublime Text via Software Center

Tags: software-center, uninstall

OS 14.4 has Soft-Center part which shows all apps, allows to install any, etc. I installed Sublime Text 3 via this thing. But I cannot uninstall ST3 via this thing, I cannot see ST3 in list of installed apps. (I press Installed, enter "subl", no thing). How to uninstall?

Comment: Have u tried using the terminal? sudo apt-get autoremove package_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can understand that you could have missed it (it is kind of a "hidden feature"), but if you go to "Installed", only a small selection of the installed applications is shown (and findable). At *the left bottom* of the window however, there is a grey link, saying "show (number) more items".

Click on it and you'll find `sublime-text`. If you click on "All Software", you will also find it by simply entering it in the search box by the way.

[image] [image]